# OK to use "Thank you so very much"?

Tags: word-usage, phrase-usage, usage, sentence-usage, verb-usage

I have already heard both

> Thank you so much

and

> Thank you very much

Is it OK to use:

> Thank you so very much

Answer (score 3):

Whether it is *correct* may be less important than if it's being used. [And it is](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22thank+you+so+very+much%22).

Just consider it as *another* attempt to add emphasis:

> Thank you
>   Thank you very much
>   Thank you so much
>   Thank you so very much

It could be a bit 'overdone', but that depends on culture, e.g. Americans tend to use more emphasis in these 'social phrases' than English speaking Europeans.

Comment: I would add that if it's a personal interaction then, "Thank you so much" conveys a much more heartfelt response.

Answer (score 0):

"Thank you so very much" implies a depth of gratitude, as in, "I am forever in your debt," or "Thank you for saving my life."